# delete a photo with afnetworking

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have a problem to delete a photo with AFNetworking in objective C.
Here is my objective c code :

```
- (void)supprimerPhoto:(NSString*)nomPhoto{
    NSString *stringUrl =URL_DELETE_PHOTO;
    //NSURL *filePath = [NSURL URLWithString:[[URL_PHOTOS stringByAppendingString:nomPhoto]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"photo_a_supprimer" : nomPhoto};
    [manager POST:stringUrl parameters:parameters
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSLog(@"OK");
          }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"error=%@", error.description);
              NSLog(@"responseString=%@", operation.responseString);
          }];
}
```

here is my php :

```
<?php
error_reportin(E_ALL);
header('Content-type: application/json')
$photo_a_supprimer=$_POST["photo_a_supprimer"];

if (file_exists("Photos/".$photo_a_supprimer))
{
unlink("Photos/".$photo_a_supprimer); // ok c’est supprimé
}
?>
```

when it executes i have this error :

```
2015-04-05 17:19:07.357 TableauDeChasse[4607:4457365] error=Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0x792b9460 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7869db00> { URL: http://tableaudechasse.fr/DeletePhoto.php } { status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sun, 05 Apr 2015 15:19:03 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "300gp=R393523723; path=/; expires=Sun, 05-Apr-2015 16:26:57 GMT";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.4.38";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://tableaudechasse.fr/DeletePhoto.php, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>}
2015-04-05 17:19:10.679 TableauDeChasse[4607:4457365] responseString=
```

does somebody can explain me what is wrong with my connection ?
It seems the problem come from the .php but if you have suggestions it would be good.

Comment: Set the error level to E_ALL, display_errors to true, and log the server response, it will likely give you enough information to debug the problem.

Comment: yes Rob, i just want to send the name of the file to be removed. How can i use the Post in the manner simple ? maybe i could do it without AFNetworking ?

Comment: BTW, the PHP code appears to have an extra `unlink` in there. I suspect that you've done while experimenting with the server code, but this is not correct. Remove the `unlink` you do before checking to see if the file exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP has two errors in it:

1. You misspelled `error_reporting`.
2. You are missing semicolon after `header()`.

You probably should return some JSON or else the client will fail when trying to parse the JSON. I'd suggest something like:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Content-type: application/json');
$photo_a_supprimer = $_POST["photo_a_supprimer"];

if (file_exists("Photos/".$photo_a_supprimer))
{
    unlink("Photos/".$photo_a_supprimer); // ok c’est supprimé
    echo json_encode(Array("success" => true));
} else {
    echo json_encode(Array("success" => false, "message" => "File not found"));
}
?>
```

Clearly you have to do some validation of `$photo_a_supprimer` to make sure it doesn't contain any `.` or `..` or `/` characters, but that's a basic idea.

And then the client code should parse this JSON response:

```
- (void)supprimerPhoto:(NSString*)nomPhoto{
    NSString *stringUrl = URL_DELETE_PHOTO;

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"photo_a_supprimer" : nomPhoto};
    [manager POST:stringUrl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([responseObject[@"success"] boolValue]) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"failed: %@", responseObject[@"message"]);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error=%@", error);
        NSLog(@"responseString=%@", operation.responseString);
    }];
}
```

My original answer (based upon original question) is below.

---

The `constructingBodyWithBlock` pattern is used when uploading the contents of a file, but in this case, it looks like your PHP is merely supplying the name of the file, so I'd do something like this:

```
- (void)supprimerPhoto:(NSString*)nomPhoto{
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"photo_a_supprimer" : nomPhoto};
    [manager POST:stringUrl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"OK"]);   
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error=%@", error);
        NSLog(@"responseString=%@", operation.responseString);
    }];
}
```

I just typed that in without the assistance of Xcode, so please forgive any typos, but hopefully it illustrates the idea. Just create `NSDictionary` with the parameters and pass that to the `POST` method without the `constructingBodyWithBlock` pattern.

---

Note the above includes a few minor, unrelated changes:

1. When you get an error object that complains that the response was `text/html`, you might want to look at `operation.responseString` to see what the contents of that HTML was (if anything). If your server reported some error in HTML response, you might want to read what it said. See logging of `responseString` in the error block, above. When you go to production, you'll want to revise that error handling block, but during this diagnostic phase, look at anything the web server returned.
2. I changed `supprimerPhoto` to a `void` return type. If you really wanted to pass back success or failure information, you'd employ a completion handler block parameter so this method could report the success/failure asynchronously back to the calling routine.

Comment: The response is empty. what can i do to look what the web server return ?

Comment: i ve just update my question with the php file, the code and the errors from debug. I replaced _REQUEST by _POST and put header('Content-type: application/json') to.

Comment: concerning my request, it s just "URL_DELETE_PHOTO" that is the correct path of my php file : @"http://xxxxxx.fr/DeletePhoto.php"

Comment: @pourpre I suspected as such. See revised answer regarding a couple of bugs in the PHP code and example of how AFNetworking would parse the response.

Comment: ok i m going to see what is wrong in this way. Thank you for the help ;)